# searching for a value in access table using java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a table on my database I called it Sender table and when I want to print the content of field it gives me this error

```
java-sql-sqlexception [microsoft][odbc-driver-manager] invalid cursor state
```

anyway this is my code

```
        str = "SELECT * FROM Sender WHERE sender_PID= " + sender_PID + "";            
        try {
            rs = stmt.executeQuery (str);  
            System.out.println (rs.getInt ("sender_PID"));    

        } catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace ( );}
```

I,m really sorry for my bad english

```
database ( )
{
    try {

        Class.forName ("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:odbc:DB");
        stmt = conn.createStatement (ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

    } catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
}

String checkSender (int sender_PID)
    {
        str = "SELECT sender_PID FROM Sender WHERE sender_PID= " + sender_PID + "";   

        try {           
            rs = stmt.executeQuery (str);                      
            while(rs.next())  
            {
                System.out.println (rs.getInt ("sender_PID"));
            }  

        } catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace ( );}     


        return "1";
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to move cursor to first record first by `rs.next()`

note: you should use `PreparedStatement` for this purpose

Comment: please make a simple example

Comment: java.sql.SQLException driver does not support this function

Comment: can you edit your post including stacktrace and little bit of more code creating connection, statement etc..

Answer (score 0):

Your rs is probably an iterator (a dataset) so you probably need to test the following code :

```
while(rs.next())  {
    System.out.println (rs.getInt ("sender_PID"));    
}
```

Comment: That probably means you don't have results for that sender_PID argument, you probably need to debug it, go the database and run the query and see if you get results.

Comment: but on my database i have some data there

Comment: First try your query without parameters : 
`str = "SELECT sender_PID FROM Sender ";`
Then try adding quotes arround sender_PID : 
`str = "SELECT sender_PID FROM Sender WHERE sender_PID= '" + sender_PID + "'";`